# How to programmatically detect usage of individual app users use of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have an app, built upon multiple AWS services, that provides a document storage service for my users.

Rather than track my users usage based on the way they use my app, and then multiplying their usage with the cost of each service they consume (doing the calculation myself), I was wondering if there was a way to do this automatically (having aws track my users at a granular per user level and compute per user costs automatically)?

For example, when a user consumes some AWS service, is there an option to provide an identifieR to AWS, so AWS tracks usage and computes costs of individual ids itself? That way it would be much simpler to just ask AWS how much my users are consuming and charge them appropriately.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein in the end, what solution did you implement? Cause I feel I am heading down the same road with the PAYG strategy I have in mind.

Comment: @Dalie still evaluating options.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are wanting to determine the costs of your service so that you can pass-on these costs to your customers.

I would recommend that you re-think your pricing strategy. Rather than charging as "cost plus some profit", focus your pricing with these rules in mind:

- Charge for things that are *of value to your customers* (that they *want* to do)
- Charge for things that you want them to do *less* (what you *don't* want them to do)
- Make everything else free

Think about how this applies to other services that charge money:

- **Water utilities:** Charge for water, but charge people for consuming *too much* water
- **Netflix:** Charge for providing shows, but charge extra for consuming more bandwidth (4K, multiple accounts)
- **Cell phone:** Charge for service, but charge extra for consuming more data

Each of these organizations suffer extra costs for providing more water, bandwidth and data, so they would prefer people either don't consume them much, or pay extra for consuming it.

If your application provides benefits to customer for storing documents, then they will pay for your service. However, you will suffer extra costs for storing more documents so you should charge extra for consuming more storage. Everything else, if possible, should be free.

Therefore, don't calculate how much each user costs you for running the Amazon EC2 instances, Data Transfer bandwidth, domain names, database storage, support staff, programmers, management and your time. Instead, **concentrate on the value you are giving to your customers** and they should be willing to pay if the benefit is greater than the cost. Find the element that *really* costs you more if they over-consume and charge extra for that. For example, if somebody stores more documents, which consumes more space in Amazon S3 and costs more Data Transfer, then charge them for having more documents. Don't charge them based on some technical aspect like the size of EC2 instance you are using.

To answer your specific question, you could **use tagging to identify resources that relate to a specific user**, such as objects stored in Amazon S3. However, you'll probably find that most of your costs are **shared costs** (eg you can't split-up an EC2 instance hosting a web app or a database used by all customers). Your application database is probably already keeping track of their usage so tagging wouldn't necessarily provide much additional insight unless specific resources are being consumed by specific users.

See: [AWS Tagging Strategies](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/account-management/aws-tagging-strategies/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions John. We do provide value - the question posted was simplified so that we can focus on the specific programming problem we are trying to solve. An other information is extraneous, and so not included in the question

Comment: To further add - the question is specific to the cost of using AWS(not the total cost of our product), and since costs on AWS change dynamically,  there is already an api for tracking pricing and costs.

Comment: Also one user may use 60GB of data, while another uses only 1GB, so we need to charge consumers appropriately. We looked at tagging, but believe it’s not the actual intention of that feature to be used in the way we intend

Comment: Presumably your application uses a database to track documents created by specific users. It would be an excellent source of data to determine how much space is being consumed by a particular user. The same cannot be said for shared resources.

Comment: We can estimate our usage of each AWS service we use reasonably well, but the point of the above question is, that to do so is an enormous cost in time and labour. So rather than focusing on workarounds or changing business models, we’ve posted a specific programming question on SO. Is there a programmatic way to get this data reliably, rather than rolling our own solution or not?

Comment: The answer is to use **tagging** to identify resources. The billing reports can provide breakdowns by tag for many (but not all) services.